# Convert MySQL update query into sequelize query

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

```
UPDATE `users` SET tempToken=tempToken-"5" WHERE `id`="1"
```

How can I write this query into sequelize query.

Comment: Hi, here nobody code for you. So try to code and if you get some errors ask here

Comment: Have you even read the docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an async function, this is how you would do it, assuming you've set up your User model:

```
myFunction: async (req, res) => {
    var tempToken = req.body.tempToken // Put whatever your data source is here for tempToken
    var newValue = tempToken - 5
    try {
        await User.update({
            tempToken: newValue
        },
        {
            where: [{
                id: 1
            }]
        })
        res.status(200).send();
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error);
    }
}
```

or

```
myFunction: async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = User.findOne({
            where: {
                id: 1
            }
        })
        await user.update({
            tempToken: user.tempToken - 5
        })
        res.status(200).send();
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error);
    }
}
```

Also, don't forget to 'require' the user model in the .js file that you use this function in.

Comment: How can i update in existing value? like tempToken column already have 10 token now i will try to add 5 more token now total and new value is 15.

Comment: @Shahrukh You need to handle the value change first. Please check my updated edit and also accept the answer.

Comment: const userData = db.users.findOne({
                     where: {
                        id: req.body.userId
                     }
                 })
                 await  db.users.update(
                  {
                     tempToken: userData.tempToken - 5
                 })

Comment: using this. but not working. showing error:=={ AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Missing where attribute in the options parameter

Comment: @Shahrukh In your await function, you are not using the found "where object" which is userData. Change that line to await userData.update({tempToken: userData.tempToken - 5})